# Leaflet Heatmap is rendering only what is on screen, if I drag the map it will re-render after releasing the mouse

Tags: reactjs, leaflet, heatmap, padding, react-leaflet

So basically I understand that the heatmap is rendering only what is beeing showed on screen. I wanted it to render more than what's on screen so that this problem woundn't happen. I have already tried to use the padding property but no success yet.

[Before dragging](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5NQRk.jpg) -> [while dragging](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jA4Rm.jpg)

This is my code currently:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useMap } from 'react-leaflet';
import 'leaflet/dist/leaflet.css';
import L from 'leaflet';
import 'leaflet.heat';

type Point = [number, number, number];

interface HeatmapLayerProps {
  points: Point[];
}

const HeatmapLayer: React.FC<HeatmapLayerProps> = ({ points }) => {
  const map = useMap();

  useEffect(() => {
    const heat = L.heatLayer(points, { radius: 25 }).addTo(map);
    return () => {
      map.removeLayer(heat);
    };
  }, [points, map]);

  return null;
};

export default HeatmapLayer;
```

I have tried this:
 `map.getRenderer(map).options.padding = 100`

but is says:
Argument of type 'Map' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Path'.
Type 'Map' is missing the following properties from type 'Path': redraw, setStyle, bringToFront, bringToBack, and 20 more.